# Замена одного числа на другое в файле python

Tags: python

Как можно заменить цифры в базе данных именно 3 столбика, у меня получается только то что все числа меняются на 2 во всей базе данных

```
for i in works:
   i=i.split()
   s=i[2]
   y=x+1
   file = open("works.txt", "wt")
   sh=file.read()
   sh=sh.replace(s,y)
   file.close()
   file=open('sh.txt','wt')
   file.write(sh)
   file.close()
``
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У меня программа работает так что заменяет все числа например 0 на 1, а мне нужно только те числа которые из 3 столбика в моем файле (txt)